# Simplify JSON value parse in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am looking for a more simple version of PHP code to parse **Win64** - **stable** channel - program **version**.
My json file is here: https://pastebin.com/GjwgmivD

My working PHP 7 code is:

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($json as $it) {
  if($it["os"] == "win64") {
    foreach ($it["versions"] as $ch) {
      if($ch["channel"] == "stable") {
        echo $ch['version'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to remove those two or at least one "foreach" if possible.

And result has to be a value: 111.0.5563.65

Comment: That is about as simple as it's going to get. Alternative solutions are just going to be hand-waving around what is essentially the same code, loop and filter. If you can better explain exactly what you don't like about the code [eg: performance of many lookups] we might be able to suggest something, but if you're just looking to remove or otherwise obscure the loops there's not much to meaningfully do.

Comment: I was thinking for a best way to exit those two inner loops when I get my value (line: echo $ch['version'];). But a use of 'break;' seems to leads to a complicated code.

Comment: Remember, `break` is equivalent to `break 1` which exits the immediately-enclosing loop. `break 2` exits 2 levels of enclosing loops.

Comment: Thanks. I have learned something new today: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP doesn't have a shortcut way to search an array by the value of a key. These loops are the best you can do. In JavaScript you could use `array.find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to avoid foreach loops by using [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) together with [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (PHP >=7): first we find the `os` key = 'win64', then with the same method we identify the version object with `version` set to stable:

```php
$key = array_search('win64', array_column($json, 'os'));
if ($key !== false ) {
    $key2 = array_search('stable', array_column($json[$key]->versions, 'channel'));
    if ($key2 !== false ) {
        $stable = $json[$key]->versions[$key2]->version;
    }
}
```

The stable version for Win64 is now in `$stable` (if found).

<kbd>**[SEE DEMO](https://3v4l.org/cI1J5)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I tried do it myself this approach but can't made it work.